# gulp serve : module.js 471 , Error : cannot find module './build/release/encode.node'

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, vagrant, mean-stack

I try to make vagrant box for M.E.A.N project from my win 10 .
mein env :

- nodejs : v6.9.4
- npm : v4.2.0
- gulp : CLI v1.2.2

---

- $ yo angular-fullstack
- $ sudo npm install
- $ gulp serve

  I got the error
  **`module.js 471 , Error : cannot find module './build/release/encode.node'`**

I try :

- $ sudo npm cache clean
- $ rm -rf node_modules
- $ sudo npm install

How can solve this error !!

Comment: Hi. i have the same problem. how you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I just solve a same issue with yours.
why don't you try this? (thats what I did and it solves my problem)

- $sudo rm -rf node_modules
- $npm cache clean
- $npm install (w/o sudo)

(I think the reason is `sudo npm install` makes root's directory which non root user cannot access, and you run `gulp serve` as non root user mode.)